# Python - Faking Type Continued

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to implement this: [How to fake type with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6803597/how-to-fake-type-with-python). I'm wrapping some .NET objects I don't control, so don't want `__new__` to be called on them by the instantiation of the class in the wrapper. I've taken the code from the question above and built a simple example:

```
class WrappableInt(object):
    def __new__(cls,*args,**kwargs):
        print("Making a new wrapint")
        return super().__new__(cls)
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.x=x


def wrap_user(wrapee):
    class wrapped_user(type(wrapee)):
        def __new__(cls,*args,**kwargs):
            return object.__new__(cls)
        def __init__(self):
            pass
        def gimmieFive(self):
            return 5
        def __getattribute__(self, attr):
            self_dict = object.__getattribute__(type(self), '__dict__')
            if attr in self_dict:
                return self_dict[attr]
            return getattr(wrapee, attr)
    return wrapped_user()
```

When I run the following tests, everything is as expected:

```
>>> z=WrappableInt(3)
Making a new wrapint
>>> p=wrap_user(z)
>>> print(p.x)
3
```

However, when I run gimmieFive, I get the following:

```
>>> p.gimmieFive()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: gimmieFive() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Why does python think `gimmieFive` is a static method, when it seems to know `__getattribute__` is not? It will happily run e.g.:

```
>>> p.gimmieFive(1)
5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are bypassing the normal [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) here. `__getattribute__` does more than just look up names on the class, it also *binds* them if the object retrieved supports binding.

Python function objects are descriptors, binding them to an instance produces a method object that, when called, passes in the bound instance as the first function argument. You are returning the original unbound function object.

Re-implementing binding behaviour is.. complex. In case of a conflict between a instance attribute and a descriptor object retrieved from the class, you'll need to check for local attributes, determine if the descriptor is a data descriptor or regural descriptor, and decide which one to return.

A simple and basic implementation would at the very least need to support `__get__` binding:

```
if attr in self_dict:
    obj = self_dict[attr]
    if hasattr(obj, '__get__'):
        obj = obj.__get__(self, type(self))
    return obj
```

This may be enough for your usecase since your `wrapped_user` class doesn't have any data descriptors right now.

With the above change, your specific example works as expected:

```
>>> z=WrappableInt(3)
Making a new wrapint
>>> p=wrap_user(z)
>>> print(p.x)
3
>>> p.gimmieFive()
5
```

Comment: Are there any things about Python you don't know?