# Is it possible to overload the return of the type method?

Tags: python-3.x, types, overloading

Given the following example:

```
class Container:
    def __init__(self, var):
        self.var = var

class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.var = Container("123")
```

Is it possible to overload the `type()` method such as `type(Test().var)` would yield `string` rather than `Container` ?

EDIT : I am using the Container class in order to place restrictions on Test.var.

The idea is that Test is a class that contains many variables, some of witch have similar names. The Container class is there to ensure that the right types are used ( __eq__(), __str__(), __add__(), ... are overloaded in order to make the Container class as discreet as possible ) so that issues are diagnosed as fast as possible ( the code will by used by people with a very wide variety of expertise in python )

The other solution would have been to use the `@property` but as there are many variables, the code ends up being way bigger than it would otherwise and not as simple to maintain ( there is close to a hundred classes witch will have to implement the properties )

I would like to overload `type(Test().var)` in order to return `type(Test().var.var)` so that it would be as easy to use as possible

Comment: why not just implement an `__str__` method, or inherit from `str` so `isinstance` would work. XY problem ?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6803597/how-to-fake-type-with-python

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre I am already using the __str__ for other purposes. I am going to edit the question to make the objective easier to understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is "no."

From [this official Python doc](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html), it states:

> Every object has an identity, a type and a value... The type() function returns an object’s type (which is an object itself). Like its identity, an object’s type is also unchangeable.

Comment: Normaly, overloading the = operator is also impossible. But overloading the `class.var = x` is possible with the `__setattr__()` witch is why I am looking if a tweak that would allow me to do so exists or not

Comment: Well, to answer the question a little bit more in detail, of course Python's features can be taken advantage of to allow this. Builtin keywords aren't reserved: `type = lambda _: str` for instance.

Comment: 'Reserved keywords aren't really reserved': yes, they are (ex: `pass`). Builtins aren't.

Comment: My mistake, you're right. I'll edit my comment. I'll take a look at your edit as well to see if I can understand the question a bit more.

Comment: I edited the question for more information on what I am trying to achieve

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand the intent. My first comment would be: "what would happen if the `Test` class simply used the raw data types?"