# How to fake user input in python

Tags: python, input, getpass

I recently came across [this website](http://samsayssweetsounds.com/). In the implore bar, if you type "/" and then some random letters, it will look like you are not typing that and are instead typing "Sam says sweet sounds".

I am currently using Python3, and I wonder if that's possible if I run it in VS Code? Could I possibly replace user input letters with other letters that are not what the entered letters so that if someone else looked, they would think that I'm typing something different? (if that makes sense)

What I have tried before:
Using the package `getpass` and then printing out letters, but then it prints out the letters in a whole new line, and not in the format user input usually looks like (it's darker than user input and bolder I think?)

Is there a specific package for this or something of the like? Thank you for any help!! Any advice would be greatly appreciated, and if I'm missing anything please let me know!

By the way, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6803597/how-to-fake-type-with-python) is not the same problem as mine.

Comment: I don't think a single package can do that because, you can ask user input in your python program while in VS Code, Jupyter Notebook or some other editor env. How can the masking be applied across all? Instead if you are building your own GUI (think tkinter), probably there you can do this!

Comment: Have a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27631629/masking-user-input-in-python-with-asterisks), if it solves your problem!

Comment: I don't know if I understand it rather job fo `pynput`, `AutoKey` or `AutoHotKey` on Windows which can catch pressed key and eventually send other keys (ie. backspace to remove previous char and new char) - and it can be used to ie. text expanding, snippets.

Comment: @anurag Thank you for the ideas! For the linked question, I wanted perhaps a different output that varies for each letter (like saying "sam says sweet sounds" instead of just the same letter the whole time). Also I'm on windows os I can't use the termios module:(

Comment: @furas I want it to appear as another character but in reality store the actual input into a variable, just like samsayssweetsounds.com as I described above in the question if you enter `/` into the implore bar. If that makes sense?

Comment: For the linked question, I wanted perhaps a different output that varies for each letter" So, instead of the part where `*` is output, output the next character of the fake output.